# Brick Laptop: How to Update Firmware/BIOS from Linux

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, bios, firmware, acer

Model: Acer E5-573G

```
mint@mint ~ $ inxi -Fxz
    System:    Host: mint Kernel: 4.8.0-53-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
               Desktop: Cinnamon 3.4.3 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3)
               Distro: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
    Machine:   System: Acer product: Aspire E5-573G v: V3.72
               Mobo: Acer model: ZORO_BH v: Type2 - A01 Board Version
               Bios: Insyde v: V1.35 date: 11/30/2015
    CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-5200U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
               flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 8799
               clock speeds: max: 2700 MHz 1: 2099 MHz 2: 2099 MHz 3: 2099 MHz
               4: 2099 MHz
    Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0
               Card-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940M] bus-ID: 04:00.0
               Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau
               Resolution: 1920x1080@60.05hz
               GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
               GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes
    Audio:     Card-1 Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
               driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
               Card-2 Intel Broadwell-U Audio Controller
               driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0
               Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.8.0-53-generic
    Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
               driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 4000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
               IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
               Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042
               driver: ath10k_pci bus-ID: 03:00.0
               IF: wlp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
    Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1016.2GB (1.0% used)
               ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD1 size: 1000.2GB temp: 25C
               ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: USB_2.0_FD size: 16.0GB temp: 0C
    Partition: ID-1: swap-1 size: 8.50GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
    RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
    Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 44.0C mobo: N/A
               Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
    Info:      Processes: 213 Uptime: 1 min Memory: 513.1/7897.3MB
               Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
               Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

This laptop came preinstalled with Windows. I attempted a complete install of Mint 18.2 with a bootable USB, but after shutting down Mint refused to boot in either UEFI or Legacy.

It seems this problem is not limited to Mint and the solution is to update the Firmware/BIOS as this version has limited functionality. In particular Acer has removed the option to "select an UEFI file as trusted for executing."

Unfortunately Windows has been removed and Acer is not providing this series with any Firmware/BIOS updates on operating systems other than Windows. 
https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/5977?b=1
Countless other forums have been unhelpful.

So here I am left with a brick unless I pirate or buy Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop uses a product called Insyde h20fft for its UEFI software. It should be possible to extract the BIOS image out of the Windows based update tool and use it from within the UEFI based updater or by using the updater in DOS mode as I've done this many times with other systems including 15 year old Dell servers. However it poses a significant risk of bricking your system as its not a vendor tested method of updating the firmware.

I suggest your safest option is to use the windows based updater in DOS mode then you need to boot into DOS using FreeDOS. It's not exactly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can install it from Linux, but did you think about downloading windows and submitting the serial number printed on a sticker on the bottom of the laptop?

if you have lost the sticker or what so ever, contacting the manufacturer of the laptop would help

I had a similar problem when I needed a Windows DVD for my 5 years old laptop, and when I contacted HP asking for the serial number that I lost from the bottom of the laptop they sent me an activated copy of Windows with drivers DVD with no fees at all even shipping.

PS: I know it would be better if I've said that in a comment but I'm not allowed to yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this person was able to install linux using bios version 1.35

http://jfcarter.net/~jimc/hardware/acer-e5-573g/index.shtml

maybe you can give a try.Make sure that turn on legacy boot on the boot page (turn off UEFI).

Comment: I read the question as "How to Update Firmware/BIOS from Linux". It's not about how to install Linux. About your link: 1) it's useful to provide the details, not only a link, which may downgrade. 2) The link http://jfcarter.net/~jimc/hardware/acer-e5-573g/setup.shtml#biosup says that the author used Windows.